# Can't get view maxX without safe area

Tags: swift, xcode, safeareaview, safearea

I'm trying to get the maxX of a view for calculations but although the view is inside a stack view (with others views) and the constraints are to not inside the safe area (and it's appear like that as well) when I’m doing

```
self.frame.maxX
```

on my view, It’s giving me view maxX **+** safe area x..
(I checked it)

Does anyone know why and have any solution ?

**--------------**

**Edit:**

Thanks to @Sweeper I understand my mistake and what I  need:

```
self.bounds.maxX
```

This one gives the right maxX.

**---------------**

Thanks,
David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the view is actually displayed on the screen, you can apply the view's `safeAreaInsets` to the view's bounds, then convert the resulting rectangle to the superview's coordinate space, which is the coordinate space of `frame`.

```
let safeBounds = someView.bounds.inset(by: someView.safeAreaInsets)
let safeFrame = someView.superview?.convert(safeBounds, from: someView)
let maxX = safeFrame?.maxX
```

From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/2891103-safeareainsets):

> The safe area of a view reflects the area not covered by navigation bars, tab bars, toolbars, and other ancestors that obscure a view controller's view. You obtain the safe area for a view by applying the insets in this property to the view's bounds rectangle.

Comment: First, thanks.
I tried it but it didn’t  work.
iPhone 11 for example :
maxX from view = 784. 
Real  maxX = 675 (from tap checking). 
Your maxX = has 632 and it doesn’t change no matter what phone / pad I use.  

Any more ideas ?

Comment: @David mind showing how you are “tap checking” this? (I.e the code you used) That would serve as a [mcve].

Comment: I’m using tap recognizer gesture.
But I think I have also calculations problems.
I will try to figure out what wrong and then I will come back here and with the correct code. for now: 
Inside touchesBegan:

       `var t = touches
        let v = t.popFirst()
        guard let tap = v?.location(in: self).x else {
            return
        }`

Comment: @David Umm, `location(in: self)` gets you the point in the coordinate space of `self`, which is a different coordinate system from the one that `self.frame` is in (it's the same one as `self.bounds`). So are you trying to find `self.bounds.maxX` or `self.frame.maxX` with safe area?

Comment: @David I think the issue here is that you are not describing correctly what it is that you want. I think you should show a picture of which rectangle's maxX, in which coordinate system (i.e. from which origin point the coordinate is measured), that you want. Just in case you didn't know, a view's `frame` is in its superview's coordinate system, and its `bounds` is in the view's own coordinate system. Maybe you are mixing up coordinate systems?

Comment: Yes I think you’re right. I  might mixed up..
I'll check it first and if I still have a problem I follow your advice and change my question. Thanks!

Comment: OK, @Sweeper you are a genius..! I changed to bounds and the magic happened. Now I’m going to read a little more about it to understand the superview's coordinate system and frame vs bounds. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, Thanks! I will

Comment: Hi @Sweeper, I have another problem, maybe you can help instead of opening a new question? 
I'm trying to add another views and I need the same maxX.
The problem is the views going into the problematic view above, with the constraint and all and I can't get the correct bounds - it always give a specific size of the parent view in the storyboard (also I clear constraint there).
It doesn't matter if it's iPhone/iPad - gives the same maxX (which is actually the frame size in iPhone).
If I call the method who loading the view from touchesBegan (from the question above) all fine.. can you help?

Comment: @David You are getting these values too early. The views have not been laid out properly yet. See for example [this](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/52578). The general answer is to put the code that gets these measurements in a method that will be called _after_ the view has been properly laid out, such as [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622482-layoutsubviews) or [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621398-viewdidlayoutsubviews). If you still have a problem after trying those, post a new question.

Comment: Hi @Sweeper, again, thanks a lot!
I also learn what to search in google. if I can ask the right question - I can get the right answer. So thank for that too!